# Local host phpadmin fail after installing mysql

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver

I was using wamp in win7 for months without any problem ie phpadmin and all pages / sites within wamp works.

Then i install mysql; much later, not realizing there might be a problem, i start using the localhost: ----

When i try to use phpMyAdmin the following message:
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

When i try to open any webpage, the following message:
cannot connect to the database because 1: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

What is happening fundamentally, help must appreciate to learn. All this happening as wamp cannot start the services. (**not green but orange in tray**)

Answer (score 0):

Yes mysql server and phpmyadmin has problems. But you can solve this by disabling mysql server when using wamp.

to do so, simply goto windows search type in "services", now navigate mysql then right click and stop services

Hope this helps and save you time